# AJAX form submission - Each click submits the form i++ number of times

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have an issue where my form submission in with AJAX works fine the first time, but if I click the submit button again, or press enter, the form submits twice. A third click causes the form to be submitted 3 times and so on. I've tried inserting `return false` and `preventDefault()` within the **scripts.js** file to no avail.

An implementation of my form can be found [here](http://www.edwinchua.tech/Articles/index.html) and the resulting list of output can be found [here](http://www.edwinchua.tech/Articles/tempdump/listall.php)

Additionally, I notice that the **scripts.js** never proceeds to the line with `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="this works3";`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**index.html**

```
<form id="form1" action="addpost.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input name="title" type="title" class="form-control " id="title" placeholder="Enter title (Compulsory)" required>
        <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
        <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="article">Article:</label>
        <textarea name="article" class="form-control" rows="5" id="article"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="img1">Image 1:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img1" accept="image/*">
        <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
    </div>
    <label id="test">hi</label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="poop()">Button</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="poop()" value = "submit"/>
</form>
```

**scripts.js**

```
function poop()
{
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="this works";
    var form = $('#form1');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="this works2";
    form.submit(function (event) 
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });
    });
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="this works3";

}
```

Comment: why don't you disable you submit button unless u get response from server

Comment: Hi Vinod, I tried to utilize `onclick="poop(); this.disabled=true"`. However, this doesn't prevent the user from submitting by pressing the Enter key. However, the problem will still persist I think. I wonder if it is a coding issue, as I have not encountered such issues in C# and ASP.net

Comment: why you have 2 button with poop thats not needed moreover instead your code doesn't require to be in poop function it needs to be on window.load and input type submit is enough to trigger submit event

Comment: I will look into adding the function into window load. Thank you :) I have 2 buttons because I wanted to make sure that both would work the same way. I had tested them individually to also make sure there were no conflicts.

Comment: Your re-attaching the submit event everytime you press the button. Either attach one submit event on load or fire the ajax onclick, your doing both

Comment: try `form.off('submit')` before your `form.submit` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Liam and Vinod for pointing me in the right direction. I included the script to override the submit function in the index.html file. Solved the problem quite nicely.

**index.html**

```
        <form id="form1" action="addpost.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <input name="title" type="title" class="form-control " id="title" placeholder="Enter title (Compulsory)" required>
                <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="article">Article:</label>
                <textarea name="article" class="form-control" rows="5" id="article"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="img1">Image 1:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img1" accept="image/*">
                <span class="help-block">This is some help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend more than one line.</span>
            </div>
            <label id="test">hi</label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value = "submit"/>
        </form> 

// script included within body of html
<script type="text/javascript">
        var form = $('#form1');
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="this works2";
        form.submit(function (event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```